# grape each entity in a single file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, entity, grape-api

I want to have multiple classes inside grape entity file, this is the folder structure app/api/proj/api/v2/entities/committees.rb

```
module PROJ::API::V2::Entities
class Committee < Grape::Entity
expose :id

expose :name, :full_name, :email, :tag, :parent_id

expose :country do |entity, option|
  entity.parent.name if entity.parent.present?
end

# include Urls

private
  def self.namespace_path
    "committees"
  end
end

  class CommitteeWithSubcommittees < CommitteeBase
        # include ProfilePhoto 
        expose :suboffices, with: 'PROJ::API::V2::Entities::CommitteeBase'
      end
```

and inside the Grape API

```
present @committees, with: PROJ::API::V2::Entities::Committee
```

is working. but if I present with

```
present @committees, with: PROJ::API::V2::Entities::CommitteeList
```

It is not working. But it works when I move it to a new file named `committee_list.rb` inside entities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing some key information from your post because you have not defined a class named `CommitteeList` or `CommitteeBase` anywhere. I assume that you have defined them and that you did not supply that code.

The problem that you're running into has to do with how Rails autoloads classes. There is [more information](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) [available elsewhere](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7) on this, but essentially you should ensure that your class names, modules names, directory names, and file names all match up. The reason that it works when you move your `CommitteeList` class to its own file is because Rails is able to find the class dynamically.

I've had to do some guess-work based on what you provided, but you want something that looks like this:

```
# app/api/proj/api/v2/entities/committee.rb
module PROJ::API::V2::Entities
  class Committee < Grape::Entity; end
end

# app/api/proj/api/v2/entities/committee_base.rb
module PROJ::API::V2::Entities
  class CommitteeBase; end
end

# app/api/proj/api/v2/entities/committee_with_subcommittee.rb
module PROJ::API::V2::Entities
  class CommitteeWithSubcommittee < CommitteeBase; end
end

# app/api/proj/api/v2/entities/committee_list.rb
module PROJ::API::V2::Entities
  class CommitteeList < CommitteeBase; end
end
```

Note that in this example I have renamed some things; your class names should be singular (`committee` not `committees`) and the filenames should match them, but making that change may cause other issues in your app. Generally, [you should use singular](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103720/classes-naming-singular-or-plural) and not plural.

I recommend reading [the Rails guide entry on constants and autoloading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) for more detail.

**Updated:**

In your gist you say that you get `Uninitialized constant PROJ::API::V2::Entities::CommitteeOffice` when you run `present @committees, with: PROJ::API::V2::Entities::CommitteeOffice` with the following code:

```
# app/api/proj/api/v2/entities/committee_base.rb
module PROJ::API::V2::Entities
  class CommitteeBase < Grape::Entity; 
    expose :id
  end
  class CommitteeOffice < CommitteeBase; 
    expose :name
  end
end
```

You get this error because Rails will only look for the class named `PROJ::API::V2::Entities::CommitteeBase` in the file `entities/committee_base.rb`. If you prefer to use a single monolithic file for your entity classes, then you must name the above file `app/api/proj/api/v2/entities.rb`.

By naming the file `app/api/proj/api/v2/entities.rb`, it tells Rails "This file contains the module `Entities` and all its classes."

Comment: With the file structure its working fine for me, but if i have structure like this its not working https://gist.github.com/anbublacky/a6e66217b2fcdeb52fe580864beecf7f

Comment: Updated answer based on gist